# problems with changing background color of nav-items with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I' m working on the navbar of my website and I have problem with my javascript code. I used the scroll-spy feature on my navigation and a java-script for smooth scrolling. In addition I want that the nav - items(links) background color change, when scrolling to the next section of the website. I developed a suitable code, but it does not function - its literally doing nothing.

```css
scroll_navbar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 14%;
 height: 100vh;
 z-index: 3;
 padding: 0;
 padding-left: 1%;
}
.nav-item {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)!important;
 margin: 6px;
 transition: 0.7s all;
}
.nav-item :hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1)!important;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
body {
 position: relative;
}
.active {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1)!important;
}

.nav-link {
 color: #000000;
}
.nav-item.scrolled {
 background-color: rgba(249,71,108,0.6)!important;
 margin: 6px;
 transition: 0.7s all;
}
.nav-item .scrolled :hover {
 background-color: rgba(249,71,108,1) !important;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center" id="scroll_navbar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="padding: 0;">
            <div id="spy">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part1" class="nav-link">home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part2" class="nav-link">about</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part3" class="nav-link">price</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part4" class="nav-link">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
 $(function () {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
     var $nav = $('.nav-item');
     $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 
     $nav.height());
  });
 });
</script>
<script> $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#spy'}) </script>
<script src="smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script>
  var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');
</script>
```

Could you find a better solution to change the background color of my links (nav-item)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're question should be more clear. you forgot to write the link tag there in css `.nav-item a`. It's very simple check it out.

```css
scroll_navbar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 14%;
 height: 100vh;
 z-index: 3;
 padding: 0;
 padding-left: 1%;
}

.nav-item a {
 color:white;
 background-color: grey!important;
 margin: 6px;
 transition: 0.7s all;
}
.nav-item :hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1)!important;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
body {
 position: relative;
}
.active {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1)!important;
}

.nav-link {
 color: #000000;
}
.nav-item.scrolled {
 background-color: rgba(249,71,108,0.6)!important;
 margin: 6px;
 transition: 0.7s all;
}
.nav-item .scrolled :hover {
 background-color: rgba(249,71,108,1) !important;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center" id="scroll_navbar">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="padding: 0;">
        <div id="spy">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part1" class="nav-link">home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part2" class="nav-link">about</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part3" class="nav-link">price</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#part4" class="nav-link">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding the link tag made my transition work, thank you :)

Comment: But the navigation links do not change their bg-color to (249,71,108,0.6), when scrolling down the window. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. To apply scrolling changes, check out this example https://jsfiddle.net/we9L9h2r/ I'm sure it'll solve your problem.